# MongoDB aggregation: FieldPath may not start with $

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

This MongoDB aggregation is failing:

```js
Attendance.aggregate([
            { $match: { cohort_id: cohort_id} },
            { $unwind: "$absences" },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        term: "$absences.term",
                        $function:
                            {
                                body: function (day) {
                                    return day.getDay();
                                },
                                args: ["$absences.formatted_date.day"],
                                lang: "js",
                            },
                    },
                    count: { $sum: 1 },
                },
            },
            { $sort: { count: 1 } },
        ])
```

with this error:

```sh
uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField.",
        "code" : 16410,
        "codeName" : "Location16410"
} with original command request: {
        "aggregate" : "attendances",
        "pipeline" : [
                {
                        "$match" : {
                                "cohort_id" : "61858e13dc5e0d1ce0238abd"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$unwind" : "$absences"
                },
                {
                        "$group" : {
                                "_id" : {
                                        "term" : "$absences.term",
                                        "$function" : {
                                                "body" : function (day) {                                     return day.getDay();                                 },
                                                "args" : [
                                                        "$absences.formatted_date.day"
                                                ],
                                                "lang" : "js"
                                        }
                                },
                                "count" : {
                                        "$sum" : 1
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$sort" : {
                                "count" : 1
                        }
                }
        ],
        "cursor" : {

        },
        "lsid" : {
                "id" : UUID("b4505aa0-e65e-46cd-8e31-03e4ecdbfe3b")
        }
} 
...
```

Not the most helpful error message.

Where am I referencing a field name wrong? Looks like it's expecting a field name without `$` somewhere, but I can't seem to find where.

I've seen similar posts about this error, but they generally have to do with `$project` and `$sort` which does not seem to be the problem here

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that's simpler and that works:

```js
Attendance.aggregate([
            { $match: { cohort_id: cohort_id} },
            { $unwind: "$absences" },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {
                        term: "$absences.term",
                        day: {
                            $dayOfWeek: "$absences.formatted_date.day"
                       },
                    },
                    count: { $sum: 1 },
                },
            },
            { $sort: { count: 1 } },
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

It considers `$function` as field name. I think it should be like this:

```
    {
        $group: {
           _id: {
           term: "$absences.term",
           day: {
                $function:  {
                    body: function (day) {
                       return day.getDay();
                    },
                    args: ["$absences.formatted_date.day"],
                    lang: "js",
                },
           },
           count: { $sum: 1 },
       },
    }
```

Is this a school homework? `day.getDay()` sounds to be a very simple function which should be available native in MongoDB Query Language.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. With this solution, MongoDB Shell doesn't throw the same error anymore, which is good, but using this aggregation in my JS code (Mongoose), I still get an internal server error, and I can't find the problem. Can't test it in mongodb shell because it doesn't recognize the JS code (of course). It would be awesome if I could find a way to get the day using Mongo operators only -- any suggestions?

Comment: To clarify, I'm using `getDay()` here to get the day of the week corresponding to a Date object.

Comment: I found a solution! I'll post it below in a second. Thanks for your help!!